# Cannot boot keycloak server in standalone mode

Tags: keycloak

I tried to run server in standalone mode but I get this:

> Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."keycloak-server.war".undertow-deployment:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."keycloak-server.war".undertow-deployment:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public
>   org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication(javax.servlet.ServletContext,org.jboss.resteasy.core.Dispatcher)

I downloaded the 'keycloak-7.0.0.zip' file, unzip it and run with `standalone.bat` file as stated in the documentation. I made my research about this error but couldn't find much. This is the full log I get

[Full Log](https://pastebin.com/HfBEWXjh)

Anyone knows how to handle this errors?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

Try to start keycloak using cmd line:

```
> standalone.bat -Dkeycloak.profile=COMMUNITY
```

The longer version:

The error in the logs mentions a wrong ProfileValue

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.keycloak.common.Profile.ProfileValue.COMMUNÝTY
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
at org.keycloak.common.Profile$ProfileValue.valueOf(Profile.java:71)
at org.keycloak.common.Profile.<init>(Profile.java:91)
at org.keycloak.common.Profile.<clinit>(Profile.java:77)
... 42 more
```

ProfileValue.**COMMUNÝTY** is undefined.

The corresponding class [org.keycloak.common.Profile](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/common/src/main/java/org/keycloak/common/Profile.java) only defines a ProfileValue.COMMUNITY. (see line 72) The Config class (inner class of Profile) provides the value, read from different possible locations.

1. System property "keycloak.profile"
2. JBoss configuration directory > profile.properties > profile
3. etc.

For unknown reason the property read by your installation gets an incorrect value. Hopefully this helps to find the wrong configuration by yourself.

Comment: I get different errors now, `Unknown data type: "¦NT"`                                   
This is new log: [NewLog](https://pastebin.com/us4XF8C5)

Comment: Again there is something with the type. Are you using special character sets? The type should be INT. could you check your settings.